# Jmeter is removing the space at end of variable in Select statement but otherwise fine

Tags: sql, variables, jmeter

In Jmeter I have a variable that has been defined with a space at the end.  I can verify in Results Tree Response that the HTTP POST has the variable substitution correct with an extra + at the end and thus know the variable and its space is being passed correctly.  Good.

Now, when the same variable is used in a select statement in apostropes, select * from whatever where value='${blah}' what happens is that I see in the Results Tree that the space is missing.  The Jmeter variable substitution in the select statement is correct for its text, but it is missing the space at the end, it removes the space.

Since the variable otherwise works correctly, how to allow the select statement to not truncate the space?

Cheers

Comment: How are you extracting the variable from the post data? Please post details.

Comment: well, I'm not extracting the variable from the post data, I was sending it.  The variable correctly is replaced with the dynamic value which includes the space.  In the User Parameters, ${username} is set to a dynamic value (for testing).  This name includes a space at the end.  The Post includes the extra + at the end to signify the space and this works fine.

Comment: The issue is much later, where the ${username} includes the dynamic text, but not the space

Comment: a select statement using the variable again, to check the db, does not include the space when it gets substituted.  Only there

Answer (score 0):

Try using jmeter *unescape* method it cleaned up those nasty '+' at the end of each variable it was parsing.

Here the complete syntaxt if you are using it in a http request parameter:  **${__unescape(${myVariableName})}**

see 19.1 http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html
for more info on jmeter function